# jquery accordion only a few expandable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

how can i do an accordion menu with only a few options expandable?  I want to have a menu

Home,Support,Sales,Other

Home has nothing in it, its just a link. so when you click on home, no expansion happens, it just does whatever i tell the links to do.

Support/Sales/Other have a few options in it. the options themselves will be links.

```
$(function() {
  $( ".leftMenu" ).accordion({
     heightStyle: "content",
     active: false,
     collapsible: true,
  });
 });
```

```
 <h3><li id='home'>Home</li></h3>
 <h3>Support</h3>
   <div>
      <ul>
        <li>New Tickets</li>
        <li>Existing Tickets</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
 <h3>Other</h3>
   <div>
    <li>stuff</li>
    <li>stuff</li>
   </div>
</div>
```

if i dont add a div under each H3, it gets all confused.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QwwVF/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that accordion needs the div after the h element for it

For example with this html it will work  as expected

```
<div class='leftMenu'>
    <h3 id ="home">Home</h3>
    <div></div>
     <h3>Support</h3>
      <div>
        <ul>
            <li>New Tickets</li>
            <li>Existing Tickets</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
     <h3>Other</h3>

    <div>
        <li>stuff</li>
        <li>stuff</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QwwVF/1/)

**Description**: Convert a pair of headers and content panels into an accordion.
[**Accordion Docs**](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: yea thats where i stopped, having an expansion of an empty area seems silly.  thanks though.

Comment: You can unbind the click for that element and then add another click event to do whatever you want see the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QwwVF/2/ i think this will do the trick